# Tomcat 6 Error When Deploying War

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, manifest, manifest.mf

I have a maven generated war file. When I try and deploy the war file, I am getting the following error in `catalina.out`:

```
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase: {0} 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:457)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:1017)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4086)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1199)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

What is this `MANIFEST.mf` file and why do I need it suddently? I have deployed probably 20 Tomcat applications that work fine without this error occurring and certainly no manifest file.

Comment: Can you post the output of this linux command: `ls -l /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps`.

Comment: @DavidLevesque lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 2010-04-19 10:40 /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps -> /srv/tomcat6/webapps

Comment: Ok, it's a symlink, can you post the output of: `ls -al /srv/tomcat6/webapps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check permissions in that directory; I suspect Tomcat can't see `META-INF` and/or the manifest file.

Comment: Well there is no manifest file. There is nothing in the META-INF directory at all. And arent't the permissions set by Maven when I run the package routine.

Comment: I was referring to standard nix permission. Tomcat runs under some user account; that account has to see `META-INF`.

Comment: Well the war is not being deployed so there is no directory. In webapps there is just `ROOT.war`

Comment: So this ended up being the issue even though the directory was not being properly deployed. It was in fact missing write permissions on the webapps folder not allowing it to deploy the files correctly.

Comment: I never suppress my first instinct!..glad it worked out for ya!

Comment: My permissions are all set to 777 for the directory chain, group and user is set to tomcat, and when I start tomcat I still get  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war (No such file or directory).... even though the file is absolutely there! annoying!